# Is Factory pattern the best method to access different databases based on the type of data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, design-patterns

I am working on an .net application that needs to present to the user data from 3 different platforms and any actions taken are also saved to the respective databases. What is the best design pattern for data access ,I am thinking Factory would be best but i need some advice as I am kind of new to this approach.

Lets say we have 5 different websites that are independent of each other completely , but similar . Products added to these different sites need to be reviewed in a single application and each product is either approved to rejected by the user . We dont need to combine the data , but the UI is the same , based on what data they are looking at , we just need to save the actions to that particular db.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the data?

Comment: Ryan -- I have edited the question to be more specific

Comment: How about a Generic Abstract Factory Pattern? Sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and is most common to use.
Look this site: http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article81.aspx
Contains a simple step to step how to create a database factory in C# for web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an Observer pattern:
(for receiving messages of new products if you are not polling manually)

coupled with a Command pattern:
(for agnostically rejecting/approving a product and sending it off to be processed by its DB)

You could then interface the brokering class with a Factory pattern. Im just curious on how you would get notified of a new product: polling, pushing, sockets, etc since that would open up more options for your solution